# Does a Jew who doesn't care about other Jews' problems become a gentile

Tags: halacha, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, tzibur-community

Under Jewish law, does a Jew who turns his back on other Jews change in his status in any way? Is he, under any law or any religious context, treated like a non-Jew for any practical intents?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Does the new who doesn't care about other jews' problems becomes a gentile

Comment: A Jew can never become an nonJew. It is like one who tried to *convert*. He is a Jew but is a sinner. Some sinners are punished by excommunication or not being trusted to give testimony but they are still Jewish.

Comment: But God describes who don't give charity as idolatets

Comment: And judaism is a race

Comment: But judai is a race and God describes people who don't give charity as isolaters

Comment: Can you check for me

Comment: Judaism isn't a race and being an idolater doesn't mean you are no longer bound by the covenant.

Comment: No, once a Jew always a Jew.